# What is the Refractive Index of a colored wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I'm working on a project that I want to compare the amount of reflection of a copper wire when is **uncoated** and when it's **colored with watercolor**. and I want to predict the amount of reflection with Fresnel Equation that reflection is a function of refractive index and ...

My question is that for the **colored** wire, should I use the *watercolor* refractive index or the *wire* refractive index or the combination of both?

Comment: Copper is opaque, and so effectively does not have a refractive index (although it might be possible in very, very thin slices). Can you find a source for a refractive index for copper?

Comment: Why do you mean? Metals Refractive index are Imaginary numbers.

Comment: Refractive Index = n + ki

Comment: for Copper we have n= 12.409 and k=78.589 ( for a light with 532 nm wavelength )

Comment: If you just use the refractive index of copper to predict the reflection after applying the watercolor, you're not going to predict any change in the behavior due to adding the watercolor. So I think you can take that option off the table.

Comment: Next question, how thick a layer of watercolor and is it enough to prevent the incident light from reaching the copper underneath?

Comment: So, you mean it all depends on the thickness of that layer